# Rails content_tag helper for simple things?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view

Should I be using the content_tag helper for all html tags when working with Rails?

Is it The Rails Way to use content_tag for even simple things like Header tags?

```
<%= content_tag :h2, :class => "bla bla" do %>
  Header
<% end %>
```

vs.

```
<h2>Header</h2>
```

Clearly just using straight html is much 'simpler' and 'shorter', but what is the correct Rails Way of doing things?

Comment: There is a good reason (I think) why you would use that helper: when you are writing your own tag helper.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using `content_tag` when you don't have to is a waste. There's no need to use ERBisms to generate static HTML so don't do it.  If some other piece of code determines what tag to use, then you'd use `content_tag` to construct that tag.

Answer (score 3):

If you are asking the rails way of doing this, then its defiantly using 'content_tag', but using tag_helpers has its own advantages and disadvantages

Personally for me I can see these things, (Using rails helpers instead of pure HTML)

**Advantages**

1 - Your code will be cleaner. (with less lines)

2 - You will have more control other the elements. 
    Ex: You can have your own helper tags like 'big_text_box' which will return a text box more than the normal with and you can use it across all the site

3 - You will be able to add attributes like class, id dynamically in the runtime

**Disadvantages**

1 - If you have a separate designer (I mean UI engineer) he/she will get confuse of by the code you have use. As its not pure html

2 - Its slow than the pure html (But this will not even noticeable unless otherwise your app is a damn major one...)

So its up to you to decide what to use, personally I prefer using rails helper tags as it makes me more comfortable

HTH

cheers

sameera

Comment: Thanks Sameera, I appreciate your input. I sure hope it becomes a major app :) Haha! I think I'll do a mix, depending on the type of tag. Everything you said makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2):

One useful method is the "div_for", which is somewhat similar to the content_tag.  If you find yourself marking up HTML elements with data you can reference later, "div_for" makes your life much easier.

Let's say you have a bunch of people being shown on a page and you need to wrap each with a div that has a unique ID so you can modify these elements with JS.  By hand and straight HTML you would have to do:

```
<% @people.each do |p| %>
  <div id="person_<%= p.id %>"><%= p.name %></div>
<% end %>
```

That would get bothersome if you were doing LOTS of this with multiple attributes (I commonly use custom IDs, classes, and some data attributes).  But using div_for you could write the above as:

```
<% @people.each do |p| %>
  <%= div_for(p) do %><%= @person.name %><% end %>
<% end %>
```

Makes the HTML a little easier to read when things get long and complex.  I found it is much cleaner when working with javascript a lot.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RecordTagHelper/div_for